# Play animation when image anchor detected

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

In RealityKit I have an image anchor. When the image anchor is detected I would like to display an object and play animation it has. I created an animation in Reality Composer. It's a simple "Ease Out" animation which comes built-in Reality Composer.

Currently, my code looks like that:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
    let arView = CustomARView(frame: .zero)

    // generate image anchor
    let anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", name: "imageAnchor"))

    // load 3D model from Experience.rcproject file
    let box = try! Experience.loadBox()
    
    // add 3D model to anchor
    anchor.addChild(box)
    
    // add anchor to scene
    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    
    return arView
    
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}

}
```

Comment: So do you have a question? Please have read through [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy. Choose Reality Composer's ***`image anchor`*** (supply it with a corresponding `.jpg` or `.png` image). Then assign a `Custom Behavior` for your model. As a trigger use a `Scene Start`. Then apply any desired Action.

[image]

---

Your code will be frighteningly simple:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let scene = try! Experience.loadCylinder()
        arView.scene.addAnchor(scene)
        return arView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Action will be played automatically (immediately after the image anchor appears).